# class java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer (java.math.BigInteger and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of load

Tags: java, spring, api, spring-mvc

I am trying to write a handler for a get request in Spring but I am getting this error:

> class java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to class java.lang.String
> (java.math.BigInteger and java.lang.String are in module java.base of
> loader 'bootstrap').

please check my controller class

```
@GetMapping("getListOfStudentsBasedOnTrainerId/{trainerId}")
public ResponseEntity<List<TrainerIdResponse>>  getListOfStudentsBasedOnTrainerId( @PathVariable int trainerId) 
        throws RecordNotFoundException{
    
    List<TrainerIdResponse> trainerIdresp= userService.getListOfStudentsBasedOnTrainerId(trainerId);
    return new ResponseEntity<List<TrainerIdResponse>>(trainerIdresp,new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK);
    
}
```

this is user service method

```
 public List<TrainerIdResponse> getListOfStudentsBasedOnTrainerId(@PathVariable int trainerId) throws RecordNotFoundException{
        
        List<Object> trainerIdResponse=searchRepository.getListOfStudentsBasedOnTrainerId(trainerId);
        Iterator it =trainerIdResponse.iterator();
         List<TrainerIdResponse> trainerIdList  =new ArrayList<>();
         while(it.hasNext()) {
             Object[] row=(Object[])it.next();
             TrainerIdResponse trainerIdResponse1= new TrainerIdResponse();
             trainerIdResponse1.setStudentid(Integer.valueOf((Integer)row[0]).intValue());
             trainerIdResponse1.setStudentname(String.valueOf(row[1]));
             trainerIdResponse1.setStudentImage(String.valueOf(row[2]));
             trainerIdResponse1.setEnrolleddate(String.valueOf(row[3]));
             trainerIdResponse1.setHighereducation(String.valueOf(row[4]));
             trainerIdResponse1.setUniversity(String.valueOf(row[5]));
             trainerIdResponse1.setEmployement(String.valueOf(row[6]));
             trainerIdResponse1.setLocation(String.valueOf(row[7]));
             trainerIdResponse1.setTrainerid(Integer.valueOf((Integer)row[8]).intValue());
             trainerIdList.add(trainerIdResponse1);
             
             
         }
        
        
        return trainerIdList;
        
    }
```

my search repository class

```
   @Query(value ="select u.userid as \"studentid\",u.username as \"studentname\",u.Image_url as \"studentImage\",u.addeddate as \"enrolleddate\", u.highestqualification as \"highereducation\",\r\n"
            + "u.college as \"university\",e.employmenttype as \"employement\",e.location,\r\n"
            + "ur.requestedtoid as \"trainerid\" from users u JOIN userexperience e  \r\n"
            + "on u.userid = e.userid  join userrequests ur on u.userid = ur.requestedtoid \r\n"
            + "where u.userid = ur.requestedtoid or u.userid =:trainerId",nativeQuery = true)
    List<Object> getListOfStudentsBasedOnTrainerId(int trainerId);
```

my response class

```
import java.util.Date;

public class TrainerIdResponse {

    private int studentid;
    private String studentname;
    private String studentImage;
    private String enrolleddate;
    private String highereducation;
    private String university;
    private String employement;
    private String location;
    private int trainerid;
    
    
    public int getStudentid() {
        return studentid;
    }
    public void setStudentid(int studentid) {
        this.studentid = studentid;
    }
    public String getStudentname() {
        return studentname;
    }
    public void setStudentname(String studentname) {
        this.studentname = studentname;
    }
    public String getStudentImage() {
        return studentImage;
    }
    public void setStudentImage(String studentImage) {
        this.studentImage = studentImage;
    }
    public  String getEnrolleddate() {
        return enrolleddate;
    }
    public void setEnrolleddate(String enrolleddate) {
        this.enrolleddate = enrolleddate;
    }
    public String getHighereducation() {
        return highereducation;
    }
    public void setHighereducation(String highereducation) {
        this.highereducation = highereducation;
    }
    public String getUniversity() {
        return university;
    }
    public void setUniversity(String university) {
        this.university = university;
    }
    public String getEmployement() {
        return employement;
    }
    public void setEmployement(String employement) {
        this.employement = employement;
    }
    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
    public int getTrainerid() {
        return trainerid;
    }
    public void setTrainerid(int trainerid) {
        this.trainerid = trainerid;
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your stack trace.  What you posted doesn't appear to be the full stack trace, or even the full message.  It is most likely an issue with your columns being numeric but your POJO class attribute being of type String ( or visa versa )

Comment: {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "timestamp": "2021-08-22T19:20:16.873+00:00",
    "message": "Required request parameter 'trainerId' for method parameter type int is not present",
    "description": "uri=/users/getListOfStudentsBasedOnTrainerId/6"
}

Comment: Your error is very likely in the expression `(Integer)row[0]` (and `row[8]`). Looks like your database stores these fields as `BigInteger`, not as `Integer`, yet you are trying to cast it to Integer. Furthermore, `Integer.valueOf((Integer)x)` is redundant. It is equivalent to `(Integer)x`.

Comment: Integer.valueOf((Integer)x) can i try this ?

Comment: Required request parameter 'trainerId' for method parameter type int is not present" i am getting this error now

Comment: Required request parameter 'trainerId' for method parameter type int is not present why i am getting this error from postman?

Comment: please anyone let me know

Comment: @BharatChaudhari what is `row[0].getClass()` and `row[8].getClass()`?

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli Please do not ask people to post images of code/errors/data. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Post the full stack trace is what I meant. I can’t tell where his exception ends and his description of the exception starts

Comment: @knittl i am not using this please check again

Comment: @BharatChaudhari You are using row[0] and row[8] and they are asking you to check what the class is with getClass(). You've also been asked to post the StackTrace. On a sidenote: Why is the error in the title different from the one in your post body?

Comment: bcz of lenght of words not accept stackoverflow thats why title is different

Comment: Q: Is the problem resolved?  Q: Did my [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68887554/421195) - `row[0].getBigDecimal().intValue()` (vs. the syntax you were attempting) help?

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of "noise" in the comments, hence this "response":

1. Q: What is the actual error message?

- Your title:

> class java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer
> (java.math.BigInteger and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of
> load

- Your body:

> class java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to class java.lang.String
> (java.math.BigInteger and java.lang.String are in module java.base of
> loader 'bootstrap').

??Which is it????

2. Q: What line of is causing the error?

   - That's an important reason you're being asked for the stack traceback: the traceback will show where in the source code the error is occurring.
   - POSSIBLE GUESSES:

`trainerIdResponse1.setStudentid(Integer.valueOf((Integer)row[0]).intValue());`
`trainerIdResponse1.setTrainerid(Integer.valueOf((Integer)row[8]).intValue());`

3. Q: If the guess is correct, what are the data types of row[0] and row[8] in the underlying database?  Do they correspond to Java "BigInteger"?
4. You *CANNOT* cast "BigInteger" to an Integer. It's possible that's your entire problem. You *MAY* use [BigInteger.intValue()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/math/biginteger_intvalue.htm).

EXAMPLE:
`int myInt = myBigInteger.intValue();`

5. Finally, if the underlying value in the database indeed corresponds to a Java BigInteger, you *CANNOT* use "intValue()" to read it.  You'll probably need `getBigDecimal()`.

Please let us know if any of this information helped.

And please "edit" your post with all the requested information.

---

Per the OP

> private int studentid; inside database this is bigserial data type and
> trainerid this is inside db is int8

So this is the necessary code:

```
BigInteger studentId = row[0].getBigDecimal();
trainerIdResponse1.setStudentid(studentId.intValue());
Long trainerId = row[8].getLong();
trainerIdResponse1.setTrainerid(trainerId.intValue()).
```

NOTE: both are [narrowing conversions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/narrowing-conversion-in-java) - you risk truncating data.

Comment: "class java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer (java.math.BigInteger and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')", this is error

Comment: trainerIdResponse1.setStudentid(Integer.valueOf((Integer)row[0]).intValue()); trainerIdResponse1.setTrainerid(Integer.valueOf((Integer)row[8]).intValue());  both are int data type

Comment: @BharatChaudhari are they? What does `row[0].getClass()` give you? I'm betting 1 BTC (or whatever currency you prefer) that it is _not_ `Integer` and very likely that it is `BigInteger`. I have already asked for the types of row 0 and 8 under your question

Comment: private int studentid; inside database this is bigserial data type and  trainerid this is inside db is int8

Comment: @Bharat Chaudhari: int8 is a Java "long"; BigSerial is a Java "BigInteger".  You need to read these values from row[] (your DB result set) with the appropriate methods (`getLong()` and `getBigDecimal()`, respectively). See my response above.